# Servicio SQL Server Agent no inicia

Tags: sql-server, mssql

Estoy con un problema ya hace varias horas, revise los post que están en este foro pero no pude encontrar la solución.

Esto me sucede desde que le saque la contraseña a mi cuenta de Windows en mi notebook

El servicio SQL server Agent no inicia!

Dejo el log del error para aportar más info

```
2023-07-29 00:18:42 - ? [508] Logging SQL Server Agent messages in file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\SQLAGENT.OUT'.
2023-07-29 00:18:42 - ? [000] Event Global\sqlserverRecComplete$SQLEXPRESS opened
2023-07-29 00:18:42 - ? [100] Microsoft SQLServerAgent version 15.0.2000.5 (X64 unicode retail build) : Process ID 7620
2023-07-29 00:18:42 - ? [495] The SQL Server Agent startup service account is WORKGROUP\BRUNO$.
2023-07-29 00:18:42 - ? [393] Waiting for SQL Server to recover database 'msdb'...
2023-07-29 00:18:42 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 229, The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_sqlagent_update_agent_xps', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (DisableAgentXPs)
2023-07-29 00:18:42 - ! [000] The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_sqlagent_update_agent_xps', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 229)
2023-07-29 00:18:42 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 229, The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_sqlagent_update_agent_xps', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (DisableAgentXPs)
2023-07-29 00:18:42 - ! [000] The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_sqlagent_update_agent_xps', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 229)
2023-07-29 00:18:42 - ? [098] SQLServerAgent terminated (normally)
```

[image: error]

Comment: Está en ingles, pero ¿te sirve [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67204425/1545868)? También puedes probar colocando el servicio con un usuario *administrador local*. Si te funciona, puedes postearlo como solución.

Comment: Llegué a esa solución pero el problema es que no puedo iniciar sesion en mi instancia del SSMS, creo que el servicio que tengo stoppeado es el que no me lo permite. Aporto imagen: https://i.imgur.com/WooYkw5.png
Gracias por contestar!

Comment: El problema es que la instalación es de una edición Express. En la edición express no funciona el agente Sql. Es una limitación propia de la misma. El agente solo funciona con Enterprise/Estandar/Web y Developer. [Sql Server ediciones y caracteristicas](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2019?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: @Javifer2 tenías razon! gracias, estoy hace dos dias con esto. Instalé la version developer y anduvo de maravillas. El servicio sigue stoppeado pero ahora puedo iniciar la instancia.
Te agradezco, saludos.